# Jquery || Limiting and smoothing movable div on mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to recreate the hover/mouse move effect the statue's in the background have on: http://toyfight.co/

What I've currently got is

```
  $('.phone-container').on('mousemove',function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetLeft;
          $('.phone-front').css({'right': x}); 
          $('.phone-front').css({'bottom': y}); 

  });
```

Which makes the phone move, but I don't know how to limit it and create the same smooth effect.

http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/evQVLV

Can one of you guys explain to me how it's best done?

Comment: You've got the code that makes it work on toyfight.. read it and find out.

Comment: @SamAxe Don't fully understand what you mean? I don't have the code from toyfight

Comment: Of course you do.

Comment: @SamAxe Could you please be less vague? :) Because the code I posted isn't the code from toyfight

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer.  To be less vague:  You've peeked behind the curtain.  You know web browsers aren't magic.  They consume plain text files (html, javascript).  If a web browser can get the code, so can you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer on another post:
[Mousemove parallax effect moves position of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761409/mousemove-parallax-effect-moves-position-of-div)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#layer-one').mousemove(function (e) {
        parallax(e, this, 1);
        parallax(e, document.getElementById('layer-two'), 2);
        parallax(e, document.getElementById('layer-three'), 3);
    });
});

function parallax(e, target, layer) {
    var layer_coeff = 10 / layer;
    var x = ($(window).width() - target.offsetWidth) / 2 - (e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
    var y = ($(window).height() - target.offsetHeight) / 2 - (e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
    $(target).offset({ top: y ,left : x });
};
```